# Writing an extra line when reading a text file from MySQL database and writing into project folder

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am storing text files in MySQL and reading it from Java into the project file. I am facing a problem in this. I am saving 3 files which contain 992 lines each. But when I am reading and saving it back in java project folder, 2 files are written as 993 lines each, the last line is an empty string.

How to resolve this?

Here are my codes to read and write into project folder.

and I am attaching the links where the files can be accessed.
[file1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61huudgcp0p6dlb/2-Aminopyrimidine.txt?dl=0)
[file2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jn6b68v1kudkc9m/2-chlorobenzoic%20Acid.txt?dl=0)
[file3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vc5nyuqljble40t/fox7.txt?dl=0)

In these files file1 and file2 are writing extra lines.

Here is the code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ReadBlob 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {

       Connection myConn = null;
       Statement myStmt = null;
       ResultSet myRs = null;

       InputStream input = null;
       FileOutputStream output = null;

         try {
        // 1. Get a connection to database
         myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "username", "password");

        // 2. Execute statement
        myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        String sql = "select file from tablename where id='1'";//I am mention the ID related to the files
        myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

        // 3. Set up a handle to the file
        File theFile = new File("data2.txt");
        output = new FileOutputStream(theFile);

        if (myRs.next()) 
                    {

            input = myRs.getBinaryStream("file"); 

            System.out.println("Reading data from database...");
            System.out.println(sql);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[2];
            while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer);
            }

            System.out.println("\nSaved to file: " + theFile.getAbsolutePath());

            System.out.println("\nCompleted successfully!");                
              }

         } 
            catch (Exception exc) 
            {
          exc.printStackTrace();
         } 
            finally 
            {
        if (input != null) 
                    {
            input.close();
        }

        if (output != null) 
                    {
            output.close();
        }

        close(myConn, myStmt);
       }
     }

       private static void close(Connection myConn, Statement myStmt)
        throws SQLException {

    if (myStmt != null) {
        myStmt.close();
        }

        if (myConn != null) {
        myConn.close();
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the stream incorrectly by ignoring the actual number of bytes read returned by the `read` method. This leads to off-by-one errors in the number of bytes you write, which results in repeating bytes from earlier reads, corrupting your written file.

You need to change your code to:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

Notice that I also increased the buffer size, as this will be more efficient than reading per two bytes.

Your code can be further simplified by using try-with-resources to close the streams.

Or even more concise, don't create an output stream, and instead use:

```
Files.copy(input, file.toPath());
```

The files may still be incorrect, as it is possible you made similar mistakes writing the file.

Answer (score 1):

File 1 is 20579 bytes long, file 2 is 20585 bytes long and file 3 is 20612 bytes long. The working file has an even length. In your code you read and write bytes 2 by 2. My guess is that when you write the last byte of file 1 and 2 you add an extra byte in your array and write it to your file.

Try to read bytes one by one to see if it works better.

Comment: Reading bytes one by one is not really a sensible approach; better would be to fix the incorrect way of reading/writing by not ignoring the actual number of bytes read.